# Android ActionMode pass _id of item selected

Tags: android, sqlite, android-actionmode, onitemlongclicklistener

I am trying to delete a record from my database.  I have this Contact ListView which lists the records in the database.  On itemLongClick opens up a menu in the action bar where I can select edit or delete.  When delete is selected I open up a dialog box that asks if they are sure that they want to delete the record.  If yes, then I need the _id of the item selected to be passed to the DatabaseHandler where a method will delete the record where RowID is equal to the _id which is passed.

```
    public class ActivityListContacts extends Activity {

    // DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(ActivityAddNewContact.this);
    DatabaseHandler db;
    final Context context = this;
    private ActionMode mActionMode;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.listview_contacts);
        populateContactList();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.contactlistmenu, menu);

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Take appropriate action for each action item click
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.addcontact:
            Intent i = new Intent(this, ActivityAddNewContact.class);
            startActivity(i);            

            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }


    private void populateContactList() {
        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
        TextView tvFullName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvContactFullNameC);
        // TextView tvCompany = (TextView)
        // findViewById(R.id.tvContactListCompany);
        Cursor cursor = db.fetchContacts();

        // Allow activity to manage lifetime of the cursor.
        // DEPRECATED! Runs on the UI thread, OK for small/short queries.
        startManagingCursor(cursor);

        // Setup mapping from cursor to view fields:
        String[] fromFieldNames = new String[] { db.KEY_NAMECONCAT, db.KEY_COMPANY };
        int[] toViewIDs = new int[] { R.id.tvContactFullNameC, R.id.tvContactListCompany };

        SimpleCursorAdapter myCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, // Context
                R.layout.item_contactlist, // Row layout template
                cursor, // cursor (set of DB records to map)
                fromFieldNames, // DB Column names
                toViewIDs // View IDs to put information in
        );

        // Set the adapter for the list view
        ListView contactList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvContacts);
        contactList.setAdapter(myCursorAdapter);
        db.close();

        contactList
                .setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
                    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView parent,
                            View view, int position, long id) {

                        System.out.println("Long click");
                        startActionMode(modeCallBack);
                        view.setSelected(true);
                        Log.w("CONTACT", "Long click item  " + id);
                        startActionMode.setTag(id);
                        return true;
                    }
                });
    }

    private ActionMode.Callback modeCallBack = new ActionMode.Callback() {

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            mode.setTitle("Options");
            mode.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.contactlistdialog, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
            int contactid = item.getItemId();

            Log.w("CONTACT", "Contact selected is ID# " + contactid);
            switch (contactid) {
            case R.id.delete: {
                // Delete the Contact Record
                // First ask if you are sure you want to delete, If yes then
                // delete, if No then dismiss
                Log.w("CONTACT", "Switch Contact ID  " + contactid);
                AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(ActivityListContacts.this);

                // set title
                alert.setTitle(R.string.contact_alert_title);
                // set dialog message
                alert.setMessage(R.string.contact_alert_message);
                alert.setCancelable(false);
                alert.setPositiveButton(R.string.contact_alert_yes,
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int contactid) {
                                // If YES then delete the contact from database
                                Log.w("CONTACT", "Contact passed to DB is ID#  " + contactid);
                                db.deleteContact(contactid);

                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        }).setNegativeButton(R.string.contact_alert_no,
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int contactid) {
                                // if this button is clicked, just close
                                // the dialog box and do nothing
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });

                // create alert dialog
                AlertDialog alertDialog = alert.create();

                // show it
                alertDialog.show();

                mode.finish();
                break;
            }
            case R.id.edit: {
                // Edit the Contact Record

                break;
            }
            default:
                return false;
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {

        }
    };

    /**
     * private void registerListClickCallback() { ListView contactList =
     * (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvContacts);
     * contactList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
     * {
     * 
     * @Override public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int
     *           position, long id) {
     * 
     *           updateItemForId(id); } }); } private void updateItemForId(long
     *           idInDB) { Cursor cursor = db.getRow(idInDB); if
     *           (cursor.moveToFirst()) { long idDB =
     *           cursor.getLong(db.COL_ROWID); String name =
     *           cursor.getString(db.COL_NAME); int studentNum =
     *           cursor.getInt(db.COL_STUDENTNUM); String favColour =
     *           cursor.getString(db.COL_FAVCOLOUR);
     * 
     *           favColour += "!"; db.updateRow(idInDB, name, studentNum,
     *           favColour); } cursor.close(); populateContactList(); }
     * 
     * 
     * 
     * 
     * 
     * 
     * 
     *           }
     **/

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        this.finish();
    }

}
```

Above is the entire class currently.  The OnItemLongClick is in the populateContactList().  There I am getting the "long id" from the Adapter.  The Log message that is there, shows the correct RowID from that item.  So now that we know that id is the correct item, I need to pass that id all the way down to the DialogBox Positive button which executes the delete record in the Database Handler.

Comment: And in the listener for the positive button what's stopping you from using `mode.getTag()` as the id?

Comment: Dunno, getting the tag returns an object not a row id and there has to be a set tag somewhere too